# Is it possible to find out the variable name, the pointer pointing to?

Tags: c

Is it Possible to get the name of array the pointer pointing to?

example:

```
 char name[20];
 char *p = name
 int door_no;
 int *q = &door_no
```

In the above example we are giving the base address of the array with the array `name` and pointer `q` pointing to `door_no` but what if, I have to know the name of the variable the array is pointing to? What is the variable name pointer `q` is pointing to? Is it possible? I tried and came to the conclusion that it's not possible but still I am trying to get the solution. What you think guys? Is there any way to make it possible?

Comment: Why would you even want to do this ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you can't do that. The names of variables do not even *exist* after your code is compiled and linked (unless you're keeping debugging information around), so you can't get at it at run time.

In C (in contrast to very dynamic languages such as JavaScript or classical Lisp), the *only* role of variable names is to tell the compiler/linker which declaration you're pointing at when you mention a variable in the source code. Once these connections have been made and represented in the compiler's internal data structures, there is no further use for the names (again, except for debugging and/or pretty-printing of error messages from the compiler).

Comment: Cool It Gave me some sensible reason Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Everything that Henning said before me is correct.  In addition, the target of a pointer might *not even have* a variable name.  For example, consider:

```
char a;
char *ptr = &a + 5;
```

Now ptr is pointing somewhere that doesn't have anything to do with a (and in fact might be pointing outside of the memory allocated for your program and doing anything with that pointer could cause a segmentation fault).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the name of the variables `p` or `q` point to if you compile and execute the program traditionally, because one of the things the compiler does is forget the name of the variables, keeping only addresses.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you may execute the program in a non-traditional execution environment where the names are preserved. For instance,

```
~ $ cat t.c
main(){
 char name[20];
 char *p=name;
 int door_no;
 int *q= & door_no;
}
~ $ frama-c -val t.c
[kernel] preprocessing with "gcc -C -E -I.  t.c"
...
[value] ====== VALUES COMPUTED ======
[value] Values for function main:
          p ∈ {{ &name ;}}
          q ∈ {{ &door_no ;}}
          __retres ∈ {0; }
```