# Regarding variables in a process memory

Tags: c, memory-management

In the following code:

```
int main()
{
     int i;
     char* s = "Hello";
     i = 10;
}
```

In memory:

- `10` should go in stack
- address of `"hello"` should go in stack
- `"Hello"` should be stored in read only memory

In the process memory, where is `i` and `s`. Where do they reside?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It seems you've already answered your own question...? The stack, the heap, and read-only memory are all part of the "process memory." Each process gets its own heap, stack, etc. That's the point of virtual memory architectures.

Comment: But, what is the character i and s?

Comment: Oh, you mean where are the variable names stored? They aren't. The compiler translates the names into memory locations in the compiled program. The variable names aren't part of the executable. (Unless, of course, you include debug symbols, but that's a separate issue altogether).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205420/is-it-possible-to-find-out-the-variable-name-the-pointer-pointing-to/7205457#7205457 explains. Variable names are used by the compiler but are not part of the executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this program:

- The locally-scoped *variables* `i` and `s` are on the stack.
- The string `"Hello"` is stored in the program `.rodata` section.
- The *value* `10` (`$10`) for `i` and the *address* of the `"Hello"` string (`.LC0`) for `s` are initialized into `i` and `s` during the `main` function preamble.

You can see this all happening with e.g. `gcc -S -o bar.s bar.c` which will output the assembly language code for `bar.c`:

```
    .file   "bar.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Hello"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    $.LC0, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $10, -12(%rbp)
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable names are just a convenience for the programmer, so that he can refer to them. The values themselve are stored wherever the compiler sees fit to place them, but the names are discarded. 
If the optimizer decides that a certain variable has a small enough scope and there are enough registers available, the variable you refer to as `i` may not even have a storage place in the process memory, because it can be kept in a register as well.

So it mostly depends on the compiler decision, where a certain variable goes. Static and global variables are always in the process memory, but local variables may not be on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The i and s here are local variables so they are stored in the stack segment. By referring i and s here are just representations in the language.